# What do i need to add to make this program work?

Tags: click, bots, autoit

When m is pressed the mouse should continously click, and when e is pressed it should exit the program so m no longer clicks. What am i doing wrong?

```
HotKeySet ("e" [,"Exit"])
HotKeySet ("m" [,"Click"])

Func Click()
MouseClick("left")
EndFunc

Func _Exit()
Exit 0
EndFunc
```

Comment: try removing the square brackets in the hotkeyset function call

Comment: In general, square brackets in documentation indicate an optional parameter, they aren't meant to be literally added to the code. You should also put in some kind of loop because right now your code will only click once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HotKeySet("e", "_Exit")
HotKeySet("m", "_Click")

While 1
    Sleep(250)
WEnd

Func _Click()
    While 1
        MouseClick("left")
        Sleep(100)
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>_Click

Func _Exit()
    Exit 0
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit
```